# Need work around for case Insensitive Linq to Entity Framework query

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have three tables Users, UserRoles, Roles.

- columns of Usres Table are UserId(Pk varchar(20)), CashCenterId(Int)
- columns of UserRoles are UserRoleID(pk Int), UserId(Fk to user table),
  RoleID(Fk to role Table)
- columns of Roles are RoleId(Pk int), RoleName(varchar(30))

I am using LINQ to ENTITY Framework to query them.

Now I want a function to check if loggin user has 'FFFAdmin' role so I pass loggin user's UserId to this function and do the following in the function.

```
     public bool isUserFFFAdmin(string UserId){

       return (from u in Db.Users
                    join ur in Db.UserRoles on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
                    join r in Db.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
                    where r.RoleName == "FFFAdmin" 
                    && u.UserID.Equals(UserId)
                    select '1').Any();
       }
```

Now the problem is this query is case insensitive so if I have two user say

1.'Ram' with role 'siteUser'
  2. 'ram' with role 'FFFAdmin'

now when I pass 'Ram' this function should return false but It returns true because of case insensitive behavior of this query.

Note* I cannot change the collation type of my database to make query case sensitve. Please help I am new to entity and LInq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the task in two parts

```cs
var users = from u in Db.Users
            join ur in Db.UserRoles on u.UserID equals ur.UserID
            join r in Db.Roles on ur.RoleID equals r.RoleID
            where r.RoleName == "FFFAdmin" 
               && u.UserID == UserId
            select u.UserID;

return users.AsEnumerable().Any(s => s == UserId);
```

By `AsEnumerable()` the second part is done in the case sensitive C# environment, while the main filtering task is still a database job.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gert Arnold It worked  (I think the best solution will be to changes the collation type of my column)